# Which .vimrc setting causes this weird copy-paste behaviour?

Tags: linux, vim

I recently copy-pasted a bunch of .vimrc settings from somewhere, and now I have this weird behaviour on text copy paste:

1. [image]
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>
4. [image]

I thought it would be `autoindent` but it is not.

**What should I remove from my .vimrc to stop this behaviour and enable normal copy paste?**

---

The fault is somewhere in this part of my .vimrc :

```
command -range=% -nargs=* Tidy <line1>,<line2>!
    \perltidy -your -preferred -default -options <args>

vmap <tab> >gv 
vmap <s-tab> <gv

nmap <tab> I<tab><esc>
nmap <s-tab> ^i<bs><esc>

let perl_include_pod   = 1
let perl_extended_vars = 1
let perl_sync_dist     = 250

filetype off
set nocompatible
set modelines=0

set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set ic
set ai
set nu

command -range Cm <line1>,<line2>s/^/#/
command -range Uc <line1>,<line2>s/^#//

set encoding=utf-8
set scrolloff=3
set autoindent
set showmode
set showcmd
set hidden
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest
set visualbell
set ttyfast
set ruler
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set laststatus=2

let mapleader = ","
nnoremap <leader>1 yypVr-
nnoremap <leader>2 yypVr=

set ignorecase
set smartcase
set gdefault
set incsearch
set showmatch
set hlsearch

set wrap
set textwidth=79
set formatoptions=qrn1
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk

nnoremap ; :
nnoremap <leader>W :%s/\s\+$//<cr>:let @/=''<CR>
nnoremap <leader>w <C-w>v<C-w>l
syntax on
set backup
set backupdir=~/.vim/backup
set directory=~/.vim/tmp

set noerrorbells
```

Comment: I'd guess it's some auto-commenting.

Comment: @Michal: no %comment% flag. Maybe it is named something else.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

before pasting, to avoid such behavior you should `:set paste` before pasting and `:set nopaste` after.

This is because the paste emulate the typing. It's even worst when you paste indented text.

This doesn't surface if you use the vim's yanking (internal "copy-paste").

Comment: Also, you can configure a shortcut to quickly toggle paste mode: `:set pastetoggle=<F11>` (see `:help pastetoggle`).

Comment: if you really make a shortcut, make it to: `:r! xsel` (`xsel` is a command line to manipulate the copy "clipboard" of x11)

Answer (score 3):

The `r` in `set formatoptions=qrn1` is supposed to cause this kind of behaviour. But `paste` mode is more suited to, well pasting. Enter `paste` mode by giving `set paste` and leave it by giving `set nopaste`. `help paste` has information.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't even have do think about `:set paste`, as you can use the command `<C-r><C-o>+` in insert mode to do a raw paste from the clipboard.

Comment: Which key combination is `<C-r>` and `<C-o>`?

Comment: It's Vim jargon for Control-R and Control-O. You use that syntax when you write key mappings in .vimrc.

Comment: You can also use "+p in normal mode. Oh, and remember that Vim needs X11 support. You can check that with :version.

Comment: Considering the OP was pasting from Notepad, which is Windows-only, there is a good chance his vim does not have X11 support. Even if he does, I have a virtualbox/vagrant setup, and SSH-ing from the host to guest, or the reverse, `"+p` doesn't work, even though both are Linux.